# How to write two numpy arrays in text file in a proper format?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to create input file that would have format like this(21 row and 20 columns)

```
0.   2900.   0. 2900.   0. 2900.
100. 2900. 100. 2900. 100. 2900.
200. 2900. 200. 2900. 200. 2900.
300. 3600. 300. 3600. 300. 3600.
```

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# synthetic model code
# 6 zones

a1=np.empty(300)
a1.fill(2900)

a2=np.empty(400)
a2.fill(3600)

a3=np.empty(200)
a3.fill(4700)

a4=np.empty(100)
a4[0:81]=4900 
a4[81:100]=5400

a5=np.empty(100)
a5[0:6]=5400 
a5[6:74]=4900
a5[74:78]=5100
a5[78:100]=5400

a6=np.empty(100)
a6[0:11]=5400 
a6[11:70]=4900
a6[70:77]=5100
a6[77:100]=5400

a7=np.empty(100)
a7[0:15]=5400 
a7[15:61]=4900
a7[61:74]=5100
a7[74:100]=5400

a8=np.empty(100)
a8[0:19]=5400
a8[19:57]=4900
a8[57:70]=5100
a8[70:100]=5400

a9=np.empty(100)
a9[0:21]=5400
a9[21:57]=4900
a9[57:70]=5100
a9[70:100]=5400

a10=np.empty(100)
a10[0:21]=5400
a10[21:57]=4900
a10[57:70]=5100
a10[70:100]=5400

a11=np.empty(100)
a11[0:21]=5400
a11[21:57]=4900
a11[57:70]=5100
a11[70:100]=5400

a12=np.empty(300)
a12.fill(5400)

b=np.concatenate((a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12))
c = b[::5].copy() 
b1=np.reshape(c,(20,20))
print type(b1)
x = np.array([0.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 700.0, 800.0, 900.0, 1000.0, 1100.0, 1200.0, 1300.0, 1400.0, 1500.0, 1600.0, 1700.0, 1800.0, 1900.0, 2000.0])

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf, linewidth=np.inf) 
with open('velpar1.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(np.array2string(b1, separator=''))
```

Original velpar1.txt

```
[[ 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900.]
 [ 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900.]
 [ 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900. 2900.]
 [ 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600.]
 [ 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600.]
 [ 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600.]
 [ 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600. 3600.]
 [ 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700.]
 [ 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700. 4700.]
 [ 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 5100. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 5400. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 5100. 5100. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 5400. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 5100. 5100. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 5100. 5100. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 5100. 5100. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 5100. 5100. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 4900. 5100. 5100. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]
 [ 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400. 5400.]]
```

How to include np.array x in f.write statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`numpy` has a great function `savetxt()` which saves an array to a file in exactly the format you're looking for.  I'd suggest using this instead of `write`.

Here's a quick example

```
   sample_array = np.random.rand(3,2)
   myfile = open('foo.out', 'wb' )
   np.savetxt(myfile, sample_array)
```